# I need help creating a VM that runs Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, kernel

I followed instructions from this website explicitly  http://www.howtogeek.com/56158/beginner-how-to-create-a-virtual-machine-in-windows-7-using-virtual-pc/

Once I attempt to install Ubuntu 13.10 to the VM I created it does the regular boot. I selected the language, then chose to install. Then a message shows up saying 
"This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU."
What kernel should i be using to do this. I also attempted this with a Toshiba 500GB portable hard drive, and the same message appeared. I also tried using an install disk, as well as the ISO that's on my PC.

These are my system properties to help any of you help me.

```
Model: HP p7-1257c
Processor: AMD A8-3820 APU with Radeon(tm) HD graphics 2.50 GHz 
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit 
RAM: 8.00 GB (7.48 GB usable)
```

Thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you downloaded a 64 bit image of Ubuntu. Your VM setting only allow 32 bit OS to run although you have 64 bit processor.

The host OS is 64 bit. This has nothing to do with the guest OS, which can be any.

If you download and use the 32 bit ISO there should be no problem.

I would recommend to use as a VM software [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org). It has more features than VirtualPC.

Also you can choose what type of VM you are creating: 32 or 64 bit.

See it here with Ubuntu VM (from https://www.virtualbox.org):

[image]